# How do I make the sty of the chapter like this?

Tags: sectioning, chapters, titlesec

I want to make the chapter's style like this,
[image]

I have tried [the following code.](https://www.overleaf.com/read/qpxsrymkbpyv) And get this:
[image]

But I can't put the "Chương 1" into the center of the first line (you see the picture)
And also I have no the third line.

By the way I want to make the table of content's style like:
[image]

But I have no idea to try.
Help me! Thanks a lot!

P/s: The full file is [here.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bo2qXq1-M31EMm_fvBB40hS7ONs7QCte/view?fbclid=IwAR2RQM6wy-U7wRNfdhn1GTz1tSjVBglVpUHpmWrJ5Nt7jzmPdw2Uvk6pEQk)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to define a command along the lines of the built-in command `\hrulefill`. It fills the available space with a line of fixed thickness `0.4pt`. We define `\hrulefillx` identical to the built-in, but with an optional argument for the thickness. Without argument, it behaves identical to `\hrulefill`.

```
\newcommand\hrulefillx[1][0.4pt]{%
  \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height #1\hfill\kern0pt%
}
```

Then the title line with the inserted chapter number can be produced by

```
\hrulefillx[4pt]\quad\textsc{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}\quad\hrulefillx[4pt]%
```

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\newcommand\hrulefillx[1][0.4pt]{%
  \leavevmode\leaders\hrule height #1\hfill\kern0pt%
}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{%
  \normalfont\bfseries\centering
}{}{10pt}{%
  \hrulefillx[4pt]\quad\textsc{\chaptertitlename~\thechapter}\quad\hrulefillx[4pt]%
  \vskip3pt%
  \titlerule
  \vskip4pt%
  \LARGE\sffamily
}[%
  \titlerule
]

% For starred chapters without number, like table of contents
\titleformat{name=\chapter,numberless}[display]{%
  \normalfont\bfseries\centering
}{}{10pt}{%
  \hrulefillx[4pt]%
  \vskip3pt%
  \titlerule
  \vskip4pt%
  \LARGE\sffamily
}[%
  \titlerule
]


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Các bài toán hệ phương trình nhiều ẩn không mẫu mực}
\section{Hệ hoán vị vòng quanh.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much but I mean how to fill green in the chapter of the table of contents?

Comment: @tthnew This is unrelated to the problem of the chapter headings. Ask a separate question. Then it is also easier to find by other people who have the same problem.

Comment: @tthnew I have improved my solution to handle all unnumbered chapters correctly.

Comment: @campa Good point. I'll rename the command.

Comment: Dear, when we write something after this chapter, the size of the words is very small. Can you make it bigger?

Comment: @tthnew Which settings do you use? My solution contains only the bare minimum to change the chapter headings. Have you integrated the lines into your preamble? In your original file, you had the lines `\usepackage{scrextend}
\changefontsizes[12pt]{11,5pt}`. Do these do what you want?

Comment: You see now in the link: https://i.imgur.com/2y57ZKE_d.webp?maxwidth=760&fidelity=grand     , that is the size is not same after we use "\chapter{....}"

Comment: @tthnew Use `\documentclass[12pt]{book}` and check the result. If still too small, use `\documentclass[14pt]{extbook}` (note the changed class). If still too small, use `\documentclass[17pt]{extbook}` or `\documentclass[20pt]{extbook}`. Once you are satisfied with the size of the normal writing, adapt the size of the chapter headings, if these are now too large.

Comment: Thank you, now it works.